Both disc brakes stopped working after severe weather: No pressure when levers are pulled
I have Shimano disc brakes (pads replaced last year). I cycle frequently enough (approx 3-5 hrs a week). Brakes were previously working without issue. Recently I was caught in some April weather:
day 1: tail end of a heat wave (mid 20s C)
day 2: torrential downpour
day 3: caught in sudden heavy snow
day 4: both brakes suddenly stop working.
By "stop working" I mean the brake handles offer no resistance, and braking power is effectively 0 (there is still a very very slight effect).
My question: Can severe weather affect disc brakes? Or is this just coincidental?
[edit] - The issue turned out to be brake pads in the end, which surprised me since both brakes failed at the same time. They are organic brake pads, so I guess damp grit must have found its way onto the rotor. Here is a picture of the bike parked in snow shortly before the brakes suddenly failed


I would not consider that normal, one of the principles of hydraulic brakes is that they are sealed so intensive to elements. I noticed that entry-level rotor (Shimano RT10/RT26) can wear rather fast in bad conditions, and it can give this kind of symptom. What is the conditions of the rotors?

Cable or hydraulic? I've had a rear cable disc brake stick due to water freezing in the cable. That's not your failure mode, but it demonstrates that there's a difference

Has someone sabotaged your bike?  I would give it a very careful look over for cuts or damage to hose/cables.

Did you do anything to the bike between day 3 and day 4? Did the brakes suddenly stop working during the ride on day 4 or were they shot from the beginning? Do you have hydraulic or cable actuated disc brakes?

The culprit in the end turned out to be worn brake pads! Something must have caused them to suddenly wear quickly. (They are organic)

I am always in awe about the scrub properties of snow. Whenever there is snow, I use it to clean my shoes by simply brushing them in the snow.
Maybe the same happened to your pads, some heavy wet snow got stuck into the brakes and then wore out the pads with some rotations of the wheel.

"brake handles offer no resistance": this looks to me that the liquid of the brakes went out. Did you swap the pad or the bike shop?

Both front and rear brake fail in the same manner at the same day makes a coincidence unlikely imo. That being said, even harsh weather seems unlikely to alone causing this without some faulty install/poor parts or some other explaining factor. From your description it sounds like you have had leakage of break fluid. Perhaps some water froze in unfortunate places damaging a seal or perhaps even sabotage. Everything is speculation though until you diagnose the actual failure mode.
I've ridden in ice, snow, slush, rain and never had something like this happen front or rear.

Basically, check for oil leaks, then. It seems unlikely that both lines would have leaked simultaneously, but that still seems more likely than the weather somehow causing this.

I was speculating if weather could have caused the damage front and back due to some faulty parts/installation. But the entire thing sounds unlikely. I'm at least counting on that he didnt flip the bike up side down, put it back and pushed both levers once.

It turned out to be brake pads in the end. They are organic, so perhaps the snow transferred some grit to the rotors and wore them down

@DJames Both breaks went from being fine to limp handles from one day to another due to break pads wearing out? It sounds incredible, but good thing you got it sorted out! :) Everything is possible. I also use organic pads, never had any issue with them even in the roughest of winter conditions (both tektro e10.11 and shimano b05s are fine imo). What pads did you have?

@DJames No. Please look for further failures. source: a friend descended a mountain with absolutely worn pads(only the steel inserts remaining). They shined blue and squealed like a pig. Still almost won the race.
